# c struct question

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct audiocd {
    char title[256];
    int trackNo;
    char type;
    char publisher[256];
};
int main() {
    struct audiocd* cdptr;
    struct audiocd cdarray[4];
    cdptr = cdarray;

    printf("%d\n", &(cdarray[2]));
    printf("%d\n", cdptr);
}
```

What is `cdarray[2] & cdptr`?

EDIT: Thanks, but if `printf("%d\n", &cdarray)` is `4291520` , is it possible to trace `printf("%d\n", &(cdarray[2])) & printf("%d\n", cdptr)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "what are they?"  What part of this is confusing to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overall effect of the program is simply undefined behavior. It's passing addresses to printf, but using the `%d` conversion, which expects an int. The mismatch causes undefined behavior.

In a typical case that int and a pointer happen to be the same size, it'll print out the address in `cdptr` and the address of `cdarray[2]`.

If you want to print out those addresses, the obvious way is something like:

```
printf("%p", (void *)&cdarray[2]); // (void *)cdarray+2
printf("%p", (void *)cdptr);
```

As for what those expressions "are", they're addresses -- the addresses of the beginning of the array and the third element of the array, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

> thanks, but if printf("%d\n",
>   &cdarray) is 4291520 , is it possible
>   to trace printf("%d\n", &(cdarray[2]))
>   & printf("%d\n", cdptr).

If I got your question correctly, I think you want to infer the values of &(cdarray[2]) and &(cdptr) from value of cdarray.

As you assigned cdarray to cdptr, cdptr will store the starting address of the array. Now &(cdarray[2]) is just

```
cdarray + 2*sizeof(struct audiocd)
```

Also, as discussed above, %p should be used to print memory addresses instead of %d.